# How to include R code within Latex in YAML header for custom-formatted RMarkdown Template

Tags: r, latex, yaml, r-markdown

I am creating an R package "mytemplate" containing derived RMarkdown format from `rmarkdown::pdf_document` (as an R script function with report as the output, it calls header.tex file):

```
report <-  function() {

  ## location of resource files in the package
  header <- system.file("resources/header.tex", package = "mytemplate")

  ## derives the style from default PDF template
  rmarkdown::pdf_document(
    latex_engine = "xelatex", fig_caption = FALSE,
    includes = rmarkdown::includes(in_header = header)
    )
}
```

Within the header.tex I use an image file detected by `system.file()` rested in the resources/ folder in the inst/ package directory:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \thispagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhead[LC]{
    \includegraphics{`r system.file("resources/cover.png", package = "mytemplate")`}
  }
```

Outside of my package and providing full YAML section in the .Rmd file, the pdf renders OK:

```
---
title: ""
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    fig_caption: false
header-includes:
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \thispagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhead[LC]{
    \includegraphics{`r system.file("resources/cover.png", package = "mytemplate")`}
  }
---

text
```

But after installation when I use `mytemplate::report` as RMarkdown output, I am returned the error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File ``r system.file("resources/cover.png", package = "mytemp
>   late")`' not found.

Is calling header.tex in the R script that's causing the error, or should I modify header.tex code and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an inline R chunk inside a tex document. That cannot work.

Instead, use the argument `pandoc_args` of `pdf_document()` to pass variables to pandoc. Inside the `header.tex` you can then use a pandoc variable:

```
args <- pandoc_variable_arg("cover", system.file("resources/cover.png", package = "mytemplate"))

report <-  function() {

  ## location of resource files in the package
  header <- system.file("resources/header.tex", package = "mytemplate")

  ## derives the style from default PDF template
  rmarkdown::pdf_document(
    latex_engine = "xelatex", fig_caption = FALSE,
    includes = rmarkdown::includes(in_header = header),
    pandoc_args = args  # pass to pandoc
    )
}
```

And `header.tex`:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \thispagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhead[LC]{
    \includegraphics{$cover$}
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I feel I'm almost there! But I got the error "! LaTeX Error: File `$cover$' not found." I made sure the pandoc_variable_arg is pointing the file to the right location. When I investigate $pandoc$args, I see: 

[11] "--variable"                                                                                       
[12] "cover=C:/Users/ONYX-USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/mytemplate/resources/cover.png"    Does the "cover=" part look right? Or should it show directly the path?

Comment: Ah I forgot, the content of `header.tex` is included in the main tempalte after the expansion of the pandoc variables. If you would put the content of `header.tex` in your own template it will work.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I will knit with .Tex created, and edit that and use .tex file as template. I will edit your answer to incorporate this information and mark it as the answer if you are OK with it.

Comment: You can modify the [default template](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/tree/master/inst/rmd/latex), incorporate the content of `header.tex` and include this via the `template` argument of `pdf_document`. Sure, feel free to edit.